# JS api decorative is not working in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, parent-to-child

the @api decorative is not working in LWC, below is piece of code. the msg is not displaying the text from parent. please help me to fix this error. I am using vs code.

parent.html

```
<template>
    <c-child>
        msg = 'passing from parent'
    </c-child>
</template>
```

child.html

```
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <div>child component: {msg}</div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

child.js

```
import { LightningElement,api } from 'lwc';

export default class Child extends LightningElement {

    @api msg;

}
```

LWC screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass it like

```
<template>
    <c-child msg="passing from parent"></c-child>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you @Aman Patil. I started working on LWC. please bear with me for small mistakes.